# how much electrical power is typically required for operating a microprocessor?

Tags: microprocessor

For any commonly used microprocessor, how much electrical power is required to operate it? I have looked it up in my book and couldn't find it. Typically, info is provided for min voltage required by it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends. If you look at the data sheet in the electrical characteristics section, you'll likely find tables or graphs showing how much current the device consumes under various conditions. The clock speed has a large impact: faster clocks need more power.

Many microcontrollers also have various sleep modes that can severely reduce the average current the device will draw. The different sleep modes leave different features enabled or disabled.

Next, the GPIOs can source and sink significant currents, even while sleeping, that must be taken into account.

And finally, everything else on the circuit board will need power. A voltage regulator can use several milliamps just to run! A different regulator may only need a hundred nanoamps. A discrete MOSFET may leak a microamp even when "off".

Your best bet is to build your circuit, program your MCU, and just measure the current.

For reference, here's a section from the ATmega328p datasheet:
[image: ATmega328p Power]